# Permission denied for access to folder on Python3.6 with Flask

Tags: flask, file-permissions, python-3.6

***EDIT***: Ignore this question entirely. It was a filesystem problem.

Whenever I try to open the `posts` folder, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Projects\blg\main.py", line 19, in index
    return render_template("index.html", newest_post=find_recent_post())
  File "C:\Users\vikas\Projects\blg\main.py", line 12, in find_recent_post
    with open(str(find_recent_post_name())) as post:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'posts/'
```

My main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def find_recent_post_name():
    import glob
    posts = glob.glob("posts/")
    return posts[len(posts) - 1]

def find_recent_post():
    with open(str(find_recent_post_name())) as post:
        newest_post = post.readlines()
    return newest_post


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", newest_post=find_recent_post())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My Python version is v3.6.1 and Flask v1.12.0

**EDIT:** Debugging code and using PowerShell seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a problem with flask. you can either change the permissions on the folder `/posts/` or  you can run flask as a user who has `read` access.

```
$ chmod 755 <folder names>
```

to give access to the user who run's flask app, or you could use:

```
$ sudo python main.py
```

to run as `admin` or run flask as a user who already has access. and note that you should add the same settings while on deployment. so workers for `uwsgi` or `gunicron` or however you run your app on deployment should run with same credentials.

note that your `user` should have both `read` or `4` access to read the file content's, and have `execute` or `1` access to be able to `cd` into it.